# Can't add geom_point to line plot with stat_count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df where I have made a nice line plot using `stat_count`, but when I try to add `geom_point` it won't work.

Without the last part (`geom_point(size=2)`) it produces a line plot, but with it I get error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   function. Defaulting to continuous. Error: Column `y` must be a 1d
>   atomic vector or a list

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
                 "bowl" = c("red", "red", "red","green", "green", "green",  
                            "green", "green", "red", "red"),
                 "year"=c(2001:2003, 2002:2003, 2001:2003, 2001:2002))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=count, colour=bowl)) +
  stat_count(geom = "line", 
             aes(y=..count..))+
  geom_point(size=2)
```

I suspect there's just a small adjustment to be made, but I can't seem to find it on my own.

Comment: What do you want on the y-axis? Now you're specifying `count` for `geom_point`, but it doesn't exist in `df`

Comment: Could you add a desired output? Also a mock up it's ok.

Comment: If you want the points at the same positions, you can replace the `geom_point()` line with `stat_count(geom = "point", aes(y = ..count..))`. Though if that's the case, putting the aesthetic mapping in the top level `ggplot()` call would be neater: `df %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = ..count.., colour = bowl)) + stat_count(geom = "line") + stat_count(geom = "point")`

Comment: @PoGibas The "..count.." I found in a thread, it works. I want to count how many "representatives" i.e. id. How many "id"s are there each year. 
Does that help?

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you! That worked like a charm. I guess I still don't understand exactly what all commands do, I just have a hinge. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible approaches:

1. Using `stat_count()` and specifying `geom`
2. Using `geom_line()` and `geom_point()`, resp., and specifying `stat`

There is a difference in the default value for `position` which will create different plots.

#### 1. Stacked plot of counts (total counts)

As already mentioned by [Z.Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881136/cant-add-geom-point-to-line-plot-with-stat-count#comment94609310_53881136),

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = stat(count), colour = bowl)) + 
  stat_count(geom = "line") + 
  stat_count(geom = "point")
```

will create a stacked line and point plot of counts, i.e., the total number of records per year (regardless of `bowl`):

[image]

As of [version 3.0.0 of `gplot2`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/#calculated-aesthetics) it is possible to use the new `stat()` function for calculated-aesthetic variables. So, `stat(count)` replaces `..count..`.

The same plot is created by

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = stat(count), colour = bowl)) + 
  geom_line(stat = "count", position = "stack") + 
  geom_point(stat = "count", position = "stack")
```

but we have to specify explicitely that the counts have to be stacked.

#### 2. Line and point plot of counts by colour

If we want to show the counts per year for each value of `bowl` separately, we can use

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = stat(count), colour = bowl)) + 
  geom_line(stat = "count") + 
  geom_point(stat = "count")
```

which produces a line and point plot for each colour.

[image]

This can also be achieved by

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = stat(count), colour = bowl)) + 
  stat_count(geom = "line", position = "identity") + 
  stat_count(geom = "point", position = "identity")
```

but know we have to specify explicitely *not* to stack.